# How do I fill in only certain blocks in minecraft 1.11.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help. I am trying to make a map, and I tried to place all command blocks with NBT data in them, but its taking too long. Is there a way to only /fill in certain blocks? I tried this:

```
/fill 607.5 12 981.5 589.5 12 939.5 minecraft:command_block 0 replace command_block {Command:"/summon Item ~ ~-8 ~ {Item:{id:iron_nugget,Count:1}}"}
```

But this doesn't work. It says that its wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The `/fill` command implicitly splits syntax depending on whether the block you're filling in is a tile entity (blocks that hold extra data like chests, furnaces, or beacons). If you're not filling in a tile entity, you have the option to replace only certain blocks, e.g. `/fill ~ ~ ~ ~3 ~3 ~3 stone 0 replace grass` will only remove grass.

You're filling in command blocks, which are tile entities. [Because of this](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-61864) (note that it's working as intended), you can *only* specify NBT after the `replace` argument, and don't have the option to replace only certain blocks.

So essentially, you can fill in a bunch of command blocks containing that command, but you *can't* only replace certain blocks while you do so. To do this, simply remove the second `command_block` from your command like so:

```
/fill 607.5 12 981.5 589.5 12 939.5 command_block 0 replace {Command:"/summon Item ~ ~-8 ~ {Item:{id:iron_nugget,Count:1}}"}
```